# Send byte array through mqtt in php

Tags: php, arrays, mqtt

I have a service (node.js) in which I receive an array of bytes through mqtt. Something like:

170617095900....
Where every byte is something:+year, month, day, hour, minute, second....

I get this from an arduino and it works fine. I want to develop something similar from php to mqtt to send another message in the same way.

I have all the data in php in an array, where every position is a value [17,6,17,9,59,0,...]

I have tried to send this array through phpMQTT library:

```
if ($mqtt->connect()) {
    $mqtt->publish($topic, $message, 0, 1);
    $mqtt->close();
}
```

But I can't. I just can send strings. So I tried to concatenate every position of my array by:

```
$message .= $mes[i]
...
```

But I get the values in ascii instead of decimals. I mean, I get an hex for 1, another one for 7 and so on.

Is there a way I can send an array of bytes through mqtt in php or I should move this part to node?

Answer (score 0):

Use the PHP ord function to convert string to byte array.

http://ca.php.net/ord

```
$fix = [];
for($i = 0; $i < strlen($message); $i++) {
    $fix[$i] = ord($message[$i]);
}
```

$fix will now contain byte array.